# How to make sense of for(int i = 5; i<=2*n; i++) in algorithm analysis?

Tags: c++, algorithm, loops

Characterize the following algorithm in terms of Big-O notation. (Assume that all variables are properly declared.)

```
for (int i = 5; i <= 2 * n; i++)
 cout << 2 * n + i - 1 << endl;
```

This question comes from the exercises in Data Structures using C++ (D.S Malik). I can't seem to make sense of it. I think I'm thrown off mostly by the conditional part of the for loop, `i<=2*n`.

Comment: This is not a homework answering service.

Comment: This is not even a question, and it's not appropriate for this forum.

Comment: @Logicrat, this is not even a forum, and it's not appropriate for this question.

Comment: @ForceBru What descriptive name that is not 'forum' would be more appropriate?

Comment: @Logicrat, Q&A site, obviously

Answer (score -2, accepted):

See https://www.interviewcake.com/article/java/big-o-notation-time-and-space-complexity (drop the constants section)

So big O of 2n-5 is the same as big O of n.

Comment: You're not wrong, but you shouldn't provide answers for blatantly off-topic questions.